# How to call a method in ViewModel from AppDelegate

Tags: swiftui

I am new to Swift and SwiftUI
I am trying to implement notification 
The notification will be received in AppDelegate, and I would like to call the function which is in ViewModel.
Is there anyway to do that ?

Comment: In this case, are you using Swift + UIKit or SwiftUI? If you are new to iOS development, I would recommend you to start with Swift and UIKit and then starting explore SwiftUI.

Comment: Im using SwiftUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have to present a view, just needing a data update. You can instance a viewModel object when you receive the notification and call its functions that you need.

In the App delegate did receive notification:

```
let viewModel = ViewModel()

viewModel.updateData(data: receivedData)
```

If you are using that viewModel in a View as a ObservedObject, your data will automatic refreshed in that view(i.e a list displaying data provided by that view model).

Comment: with viewModel in a View as a ObservedObject, the object seems to be a different instance, do I need to pass the viewModel as an environmentObject ?

Comment: If you are presenting the view and you receive a notification on data update, then you can pass the viewModel as an environmentObject. If possible, provide some code to help you better.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I got what I want